# How to remove part of text in a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a smarty template which I can edit HTML and place JavaScript only, but cannot edit the php code.

**The list looks like this:**

```
<select>
  <option id="1" value="first">{$line1}</option>
  <option id="2" value="second">{$line2}</option>
</select>
```

Where in the live page, `{$line1}` displayed as `green` and `{$line2}` displayed as `black and white`.

I want to place a JavaScript or jQuery code to take out (remove) the `and white` text from `{$line2}` in order to show the `black` only. Any suggestions? Your answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$("option[value=second]").text("Black")`

Comment: variables in the template and hard-coded values in javascript probably isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dynamic solution:

```
$('select option').each(function(i, item){
        var words = $(item).text().split(' ');
        $(item).text(words[0]);
    });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qo4wytd6/)

Answer (score 2):

To Remove options from a dropdown, you would simply do something like this by using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "";

document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "black";
```

this way, the black and white would be set to " " or nothing at all and then to "black" If you would like it to change to another piece of text, change "black" to something else.

Comment: What is the benefit of setting it to an empty string first?

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, great pure JS solution. But why set it to `""` before setting it to `"black"`?

Comment: Oh, haha :P just realized doing document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = ""; is useless. I just was making sure that it was reset because in case it became black and black and white.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, demo at **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/32jx43kx/)**

```
if ($('select option#2').text().indexOf('and white') > 0){
  $('select option#2').text('black');
}
```

Comment: Nope.  Look what happens when I [edit your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32jx43kx/2/), changing the text in the option to "black and brown".  The option text is still changed to "black", even though it didn't contain "and white".

Comment: Since he is using variables (`{$line1}`) for his option text it probably wouldn't be a good idea to hard-code the values in javascript

Answer (score 1):

As said by [dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis) in the comments, you can set the value of the option using this code:

```
$('option[value=second]').text('Black')
```

However, let's say your text is dynamic and you want to always cut off anything past the first word (i.e. `'Black and white'` → `'Black'` or `'Red and yellow'` → `'Red'`), then you will want to use something like this:

```
var opt = $('option[value=second]');
opt.text(opt.text().split(' ')[0]);
```

**Explanation:**

The `opt.text()` gets the text of the `option`.

The `split(' ')` splits up the string into an array by the spaces in the text.

> *Example:* the string: `'strings are awesome'` would become an array of strings: `['strings', 'are', 'awesome']` using that split.

The `[0]` gets the first string from that array. (Which in your case happens to be `'Black'`.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! it helped so much, but unfortunately didn't work for me or any of the other answers. I placed the code like this `{literal} <script type="text/javascript"> var opt = $('option[value=second]'); opt.text(opt.text().split(' ')[0]); </script> {/literal}` but nothing has changed! I think I need to put something in the code to overwrite or to have the highest priority over the original code. Like the `!important` in CSS. Thank you again for your time :)