# Output first 2 words from a string that contains 3 words

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to display the first 2 words from a string that contains 3 words (for example).

I have the following code from my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112005/how-to-remove-part-of-text-in-a-dropdown-list).

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qo4wytd6/) of code by [zgood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179077/zgood).

```
$('select option').each(function(i, item){
    var arr = $(item).text().split(' ');
    $(item).text(arr[0]);
});
```

The code is working fine but displays only first word. I tried to make it display 2 words but  I had no luck. So, if anyone can tell how to make it displays the first 2 words of my string, that would be great.

Comment: the second word is  $(item).text(arr[1]);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods:

```
$('select option').text(function(_, currentText) {
    return currentText.split(' ').slice(0, 2).join(' ');
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this code if this for for a class or for a job interview and you can't explain what those functions are doing .... otherwise , this will probably be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the same with the regex

```
$('select option').each(function(i, item){
    var text = $(item).text();
    var regex = /\w+\s+\w*/
    var groups = text.match(regex) || [];
    $(item).text(groups[0]);
});
```

Here is [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qo4wytd6/1/)